# Cannot read MP4 files with openCV (3.2.0) - Python (2.7.13)

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, mp4

I am (unfortunately) absolutely new to both Python and OpenCV, but I'd like to use OpenCV (3.2.0) with Python (2.7.13) bindings to extract specific frames from `.mp4` files.

I tried to follow the "Getting Started with Videos" tutorial to learn how to play video files (http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), but even though I was able to `VideoCapture(0)` (i.e. stream the web cam), I was not able to play a video file (mp4): I used the following code named "Untitled.py":

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('PathToVideoFile\film.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is all I get:

```
================== RESTART: C:\Python27\Scripts\Untitled.py ==================
```

(and nothing else...)

I downloaded ffmpeg and copied the opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll from `opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin` into `C:\Python27` but it did not help... Can you please help me with this issue?

Plese let me know if you need more information about the issue and sorry if my question is due to me missing something trivial.

Thank you very much in advance!

Adrien

Answer (score 0):

Video camera capture output is in RGB, not the same format as video file for playback. Video file is usually compressed and need a correct codec to decode.

If `opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll` is not in `%OPENCV_DIR%\bin`, video playback won't work. For `OPENCV_DIR` environment variable setup, below is the example and subjects to your installation.

- `OPENCV_DIR=C:\Program Files\OpenCV 3.2.0\x64\vc14`
- `Path=%OPENCV_DIR%\bin;%Path%`

Also check the properties of your `opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll` file. Its size is about `16.5 MB (17,397,760 bytes)` if compiled by VS2015 on Win10 64-bit platform for Python 2.7.

Your Python code works in my PC. From the question above, seems you incorrectly copied the FFMPEG DLL to Python's directory.

Comment: Either that... or you didn't add `C:\opencv\build\bin` to the system's PATH environment variable!